# How to spoof the google search result with different Geo location

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, geolocation

Do we have any way to bypass the actual geo location in google search result page.

In the Google result end of page, we can see the phrase "Based on your past activity". how it picks this ? and need to set it other geolocation.

Thanks
KSk

Comment: this question is [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on superuser

Comment: In addition to the 2 answers, make sure you are not logged in. Its best to do this in an in-private browser session. This ensures that google won't alter the search results based on what it already collected about you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Google Chrome `sensors`.

Pop open the Developer panel (<kbd>F12</kbd>), and in the bottom section of the console choose `Sensors`. In the Location sensor, choose an alternate location. If you don't see the Console, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or click the `.` menu and choose `Show console drawer`.

[image]

To add/edit locations, click `Manage`.

Now when I search for my location, I see a result based on my Sensor value.

[image]

For reference, I'm not in Tokyo.

Answer (score 1):

To make applications think that you are elsewhere in the world,
use a VPN with a server in that location.

See Gizmo's
[Best VPN Services for 2021](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-vpn-services.htm).